# How to convert int into char* in C (without sprintf)

Tags: c, char, int, printf

some day, i wanted to convert in C an integer into a char *, this int can be negative.

I wasn't able to use sprintf ,snprintf neither, so how do i do that ?

Comment: `snprintf()`? Open a pipe and `fprintf()` into it, read the integer from it?

Comment: Why aren't you able to use `sprintf`? If you can't use it, then chances are that you can't use other functions as well. Which library functions can you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To roll one's own `itoa()`-like function, first one must address how to handle memory.  The easiest is to use a large-enough memory for all possible `int` values (`INT_MIN`).

The buffer required size is mathematically `ceiling(log10(-INT_MIN))+3`.  This can be approximated with:

```
#include <limits.h>
#define INT_STR_SIZE (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)
```

Then build the digits up one-by-one starting with the least significant digit using `%10` and then `/10` to reduce the value.

By using a `do` loop, code catches the corner case of `x==0` as at least one digit is made.

This code avoids `if (x < 0) { x = -x; ...` as negating `INT_MIN` (or multiplying by -1 leads to `int` overflow, which is UB.

```
#include <limits.h>
#define INT_STR_SIZE (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)

char *my_itoa(char *dest, size_t size, int x) {
  char buf[INT_STR_SIZE];
  char *p = &buf[INT_STR_SIZE - 1];
  *p = '\0';
  int i = x;

  do {
    *(--p) = abs(i%10) + '0';
    i /= 10;
  } while (i);

  if (x < 0) {
    *(--p) = '-';
  }
  size_t len = (size_t) (&buf[INT_STR_SIZE] - p);
  if (len > size) {
    return NULL;  // Not enough room
  }
  return memcpy(dest, p, len);
}
```

With C99 or later, code can handle the buffer creation with a *compound literal* allowing separate buffers for each `mt_itoa()` call.

```
// compound literal C99 or later
#define MY_ITOA(x) my_itoa((char [INT_STR_SIZE]){""}, INT_STR_SIZE, x)

int main(void) {
  printf("%s %s %s %s\n", MY_ITOA(INT_MIN), MY_ITOA(-1), MY_ITOA(0), MY_ITOA(INT_MAX));
  return (0);
}
```

Output

```
-2147483648 -1 0 2147483647
```

Answer (score -2):

to convert from integer to char* use the function itoa().
/* itoa example */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  int i;
  char buffer [33];
  printf ("Enter a number: ");
  scanf ("%d",&i);
  itoa (i,buffer,10);
  printf ("decimal: %s\n",buffer);
  itoa (i,buffer,16);
  printf ("hexadecimal: %s\n",buffer);
  itoa (i,buffer,2);
  printf ("binary: %s\n",buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `itoa()` is not standard c.

Comment: How is that and It's a part of stdlib ?

Comment: Where is `itoa()` standardized? It's not in C11 draft standard n1570, nor C99 draft standard n1256.

Comment: it's in C11 draft standard n 1570

Comment: Can you cite the clause or page number where `itoa()` is mentioned?

Comment: oo sorry, i got confused it's atoi .you are right,thank you.