# Static char array return from function Provides incorrect answer

Tags: c

according this code:

```
int main(){
    int x=1;
    int y=2;
    printf(" %s + %s = %s ", function(x) , function(y), function(x+y));
}

char* function(int num){
    static char B[20];
    sprintf(B,"%d",num);
    return B;
}
```

The answer I got is: 1 + 1 = 1

and the question is why?

Why if I am separating the lines like this:

```
int main(){
    int x=1;
    int y=2;
    printf("%s +" function(x));
    printf(" %s =" function(y));
    printf(" %s"function(x+y));
}
```

I got the correct answer as I expected ???

Comment: Because there is only one array

Comment: [Work-a round](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36380105/2410359)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `function` always returns the same value, namely a pointer pointing to the start of the static array `B`.

In the first code snippet, you call `funtion` three times as part of a call to `printf`.  When calling a function, each of its parameters must be evaluated before the function is called.  This means that `function` is called 3 times before `printf` is called, so `B` only contains the most recent value stored there.  This means you end up printing the same thing 3 times.

Also, the order in which arguments to a function are evaluated is unspecified, so you don't which call to `function` will be last.  The value printed three times could be either 1, 2, or 3.

In the second snippet, since you only call `function` once in each `printf` call, there is no ambiguity regarding what will be printed.

Comment: But at each function call the value of array B changes.
If so, as you say - it stores the most recent value then the print should be 3 + 3 = 3 ?

Comment: @avimenashe The order of evaluation of function call arguments is unspecified.

Answer (score 3):

As there is only *one* buffer `B`, it gets overwritten with every function call. Because your `printf` call in `main` calls the function 3 times, `sprintf` finds the same buffer all three times. And there is no guarantee about the order in which your function would be called in the evaluation of the function arguments.